# How to proof that a dual basis applied to the basis give the Kronecker delta?

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, manifolds, kronecker-delta

Since a long time I was wondering how can we build proof that a basis applies to its dual give the Kronecker delta. I'm now following [on-line lectures related to topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G4SqIboeig&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=1) and find out that there is a proper way of doing this.

This proof, I think, will be useful to understand [differential form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845510/understanding-differential-form-from-do-carmo/845592#845592) and 
other [somewhat related subjects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952090/compute-df-p-big-frac-partial-partial-x-big-big-p).

But I'm stock at the end of the proof. Lets first start with some context.

Proof that: $\left(dx^a\right)_p \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b}\right)_p\right) = \delta^a_b$

**Context :**
On a smooth manifold $(M,\mathscr{O}_M,\mathscr{A}_{C^\infty})$ let there be a point $p$, a curve $\gamma$, $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to M$, where $\gamma(0)=p$ and a function $f: M\to \mathbb{R}$.

The velocity at the point $p$ is defined as :

$v_\gamma,_p : = (f\circ \gamma)^\prime(0)$

From a chart $(U,x)\in \mathscr{A}_{C^\infty}$ consider $x: U \to \mathbb{R}^d$ in particular $x^i: U \to \mathbb{R}$

$v_\gamma,_p = \left((f \circ x^{-1}) \circ (x \circ \gamma)\right)^\prime(0)
= (x^i \circ \gamma)^\prime(0) \cdot \left(\partial_i(f \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p))$

since $(x\circ\gamma)(0)= x(p)$.

**Definition 1**: By convention we right the notation:

$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p := \left(\partial_i(f \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p))$

It is the vector basis $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p := e_i \in T_pM$

**Definition 2**: The dual basis is defined as the set of linear maps from $T_pM$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as fallow $T^*_pM := \{ \phi:T_pM \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{R} \}$. In particular $(df)_p$ is defined:

$(df)_p :T_pM \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{R}$

where

$X \mapsto (df)_p(X) :=Xf$

for a vector $X$ under the chart $(U,x)$ defines as $X:=X^i_{(x)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p$

**Proof :**
By applying the definition 2, $(df)_p(X) :=Xf$, we have that:

$\left(dx^a\right)_p \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b}\right)_p\right) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b}\right)_p(x^a)= \left(\partial_b(x^a \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p)) $

Now it is obvious that if we take the notation $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b}\right)_p(x^a)$ and apply undergraduate analysis we have $\delta_b^a$ but the question is what to do with the real thing: $\left(\partial_b(x^a \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p)) $

**Question**

Why should $\left(\partial_b(x^a \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p))$ equal $\delta_b^a$ ? If this is not the case, where is my mistake ?

**Edit :**

Differentiation of $x$ or $x^{-1}$ is not allowed since $x:U\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is not a $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ map and there is no differential operation define on the manifold the chart map is needed for that !

But 
$x^a \circ x^{-1} = \operatorname{id}^a$

so $\left(\partial_b(\operatorname{id}^a)\right)(x(p))$

**Confusion**

I'm confuse and I don't see how to get simply $\delta^a_b$ from these equations.

Thanks for your comment,

NLC

Comment: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of a vector space $V$. A dual basis $\mathcal{B}^{*}$ of the dual space $V^{*}$ gives the Kronecker delta (when evaluated on each vector of $\mathcal{B}$) by definition.

Comment: Because $x^a \circ x^{-1} : \underset{\in \mathbb{R}^d}{\left(x^1(p),\dots,x^d(p)\right)} \mapsto \underset{\in \mathbb{R}}{x^a(p)}$ it seam to me that $\left(\partial_b(x^a \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p))=\left(\partial_b(x^a)\right)(p)$. Is this correct ?

Comment: From one class of [Fredric Schuller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&feature=youtu.be) I learned that this $\partial_b(x^a \circ x^{-1})=\delta^a_b$ from the definition of the derivation on the "b" entry on a projection of the "a" entry.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a vector space with basis $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, then the **dual set** $\mathcal{B}^{*}=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ is ***defined by*** the equations: 
$$f_{i}:V\longrightarrow\mathbb{K}$$
$$f_{i}(v_j):=\delta_{i,j}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if} \ i=j\\ 0 & \text{if} \ i\neq j\end{cases}$$ 
this set turns out to be a basis of the dual space $V^{*}:=\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb{K})$. In effect, the functionals $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are linearly independent:
$$\text{If} \quad \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\cdot f_{i}=0_{V^{*}},\quad \text{then}$$
then we evaluate on each basis vector $v_{j}$ to get:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\cdot f_{i}(v_{j})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\cdot f_{i}\right)(v_{j})=0_{V^{*}}(v_{j})=0_{\mathbb{K}},\ \forall\, j$$
thus,
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\cdot f_{i}(v_{j})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\delta_{i,j}=\lambda_{j},\ \forall\, j$$.
so $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_{n}=0_{\mathbb{K}}$. Then, $\mathcal{B}^{*}$ is a basis of $V^{*}$ called the dual basis of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
the question is actually  more why should $\left(\partial_b(x^a \circ x^{-1})\right)(x(p))$ be equal to $\delta_b^a$. And if it is not what is the mistake I have made !